# Printing Excel File Name to Text File - Why am I getting false?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the small script I wrote:

```
    Option Explicit
Dim strFileFullName As String
Sub saveToText()
Open "PATH\File.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, strFileFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Print #1, Sheets("Overview").Range("D14").Text
Close #1
End Sub
```

Also I would like to add some extra text to the .txt file that is not in the excel workbook. How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: `print #1, "your extra text here"`?

Comment: You're getting False because you're printing the result of the test `strFileFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName` - those two are not equal, so you get False.  If you just want to print the name of the workbook then just use `Print #1, ActiveWorkbook.FullName
 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB does not have a distinction between the comparison operator and the assignment operator. That is, they are both `=`. In this case, it is being interpreted as the comparison operator, which is returning false. (Compare this to C, where the comparison operator is `==` and the assignment operator is `=`; what you are trying to do here would work in C as an inline assign)

It doesn't look like you need the extra variable there, so you should be able to just do:

```
Print #1, ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Or, use two statements (VB will understand this as an assignment, not a comparison):

```
strFileFullName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Print #1, strFileFullName
```

---

Adding text is as simple as adding another print statement:

```
Print #1, "Lorem ipsum dolor"
```

Comment: It's printing the string of the file path and not the name of the document. Any way to go around this? Also, could I get it to clear the contents of the text file before writing all this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`Workbook.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820899.aspx) instead?

Comment: Yeah if that gives me just the string value of what the excel file is named. How do I clear the contents of the text file? I tried using Kill but, I got some errors, and overwriting the contents would be easier.

Comment: If you want to just overwrite the contents you can open it for `Output` instead of `Append`